# Making text and a right-floated div appear on one line inside their flexible container--without more HTML

Tags: css, css-float

Using CSS only, I'm trying to force a right-floated element NOT to clear its left-aligned sibling text without giving the parent container a width. The parent is block level, but floated. Basically, the container needs to always be the smallest width possible to fit the text node and the `<div>` on one line, and they need to actually *render* on one line.

For example, the right floated `div` here will always jump down to the line below the text node:

```
#demo {float:left;border:solid 1px blue;}       
#demo div {float:right;border:solid 1px green;}   

<div id="demo">
  Text Node!
  <div>right-floated</div>
</div>
```

The big constraint is that I can't change the HTML at all--I can't add a `<span>` tag around the text node, and I can't switch the order so that the text node comes second. Switching the order would solve the problem.

The other thing is that I don't want to specify a width for the containing element because the content width will vary wildly. This may not be possible using just CSS, but I just wanted to see if anyone has a brilliant trick.

Comment: Is `#demo div {display:inline;}` a [valid solution](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Kb362/)? Seems too easy..

Comment: This is very strange, but I tried that and it didn't work, but it IS working on JSFIDDLE. However, I can't seem to get it to work in my page... I wonder if it's a quirk in JSFIDDLE or if it's something in my page interfering?

Comment: Something on your page is probably interfering. Try `#demo div { float: none !important; display: inline !important }`. `!important` to rule out specificity problems (unless you're using `!important` elsewhere), and `float: none` because `display: inline` won't do anything if the element is floated (`display` is forced to `block`).

Comment: Ok, even weirder. If I copy the source code from my page (where it isn't working) into notepad and save it as demo.html, then it does work. There is some sort of interference here that I need to track down. Thanks!

Comment: That works, but I can't kill the `float:right;` though. Needs to float to the right in a few edge-cases where the container has a min-width specified, which will expand some, but not all, instances of this.

Comment: How about `margin-top: -??px` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Kb362/1/))? Also, why can't you change the HTML? Often, "I can't change the HTML" means "I don't understand my CMS properly".

Comment: That would work if the height wasn't variable. I'm thinking at this point there isn't a way to do this just using CSS. :( I ultimately had to create three or four classes for different situations and put the class in depending on the scenario.
(BTW, HTML isn't editable due to some backend constraints. I'm not a I just have to take the backend developers' word for it.